# Windows 10 user sign on issue

Tags: windows-10

We have a user sign on that is mainly used remotely by someone. About every 30 days windows asks us to change the password. Is there someway I can turn this off.

Thanks. 
Lorienne

Comment: "Is there someway I can turn this off." - Yes, but it requires you be an Administrator on the AD domain.  This cannot be done if you are not an AD domain Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a domained joined pc (Correct me if I'm wrong). If so, check with your GPO on your DC Server on how many days are set for all your users to reset their password, I believe the default policy on domain is 30 days. You can make exception on Active directory very easily, search for the user and on the user's account properties, set password to (password never expires).

Comment: The author is obviously not an Administrator on the domains

Answer (score 0):

If it is domain environment, log on using the user account, open **CMD** and type “***gpresult /r***” to display all applied group policies.

As far as I know, there are GP such as “**Password Policy: maximum Password age**”, it is used to periodically force users to change their passwords after specific time/day.

**Configuring Password Policies**:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277399.aspx

If it is local workgroup, run “***gpedit.msc***” to open **Local Group Policy Editor**. Open below location:
***Computer Configuration – Windows Settings – Security Settings – Account Policies - maximum Password age***.

You can manually disable this policy, or, change the maximum days.